# Django CVB attribute with parenthesis

Tags: python, django

I am trying to learn Django using the Book Django unleashed. In chapter 9, the author is rewriting a form display method to a Class-Based View (CBV). I am trying to understand why a set of parenthesis were used when a class attribute was called. I am assuming it is since the class attribute is going to store a form object, but I wanted to further understand it.

```
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404, redirect
from .models import Tag, Startup
from .forms import TagForm
from django.views.generic import View

class PostCreate(View):
    form_class = PostForm
    template_name = 'blog/post_form.html'

    def get(self, request):
        return render(
            request,
            self.template_name,
            {'form': self.form_class()})

    def post(self, request):
        bound_form = self.form_class(request.POST)
        if bound_form.is_valid():
            new_post = bound_form.save()
            return redirect(new_post)
        else:
            return render(
                request,
                self.template_name,{'form': bound_form})
```

As you can see, on the 14 line the code is

```
    {'form': self.form_class()})
```

But on the last line, the code is

```
            self.template_name,
```

I am confused as to why the author used parenthesis on the first class attribute and not the second. Can you please explain that

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am confused as to why the author used parenthesis on the first class attribute and not the second. Can you please explain that.

In `get` the author used `self.form_class()` i.e. actually `PostForm()` because `self.form_class` is just the reference to `PostForm` class so when `self.form_class` with parenthesis i.e. `self.form_class()` it is the instance of `PostForm` with no arguments passed.

and

in `post` method author is passing `request.POST` to the `self.form_class` which is again just reference to `PostForm`, so now it is `PostForm(request.POST)`  and assigning it to variable `bound_form`, hence `bound_form` is passed as it is.

Hope this clears your confusion